# How to get an element by its href in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-framework

I want to get an element by its href attribute in jquery or javascript.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery's [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for that.

```
var linksToGoogle = $('a[href="https://google.com"]');
```

Alternatively, if your interest is rather links *starting* with a certain URL, use the [attribute-starts-with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
var allLinksToGoogle = $('a[href^="https://google.com"]');
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want to get any element that has part of a URL in their href attribute you could use:

```
$( 'a[href*="google.com"]' );
```

This will select all elements with a href that contains google.com, for example:

- http://google.com
- http://www.google.com
- https://www.google.com/#q=How+to+get+element+by+href+in+jquery%3F

As stated by @BalusC in the comments below, it will also match elements that have `google.com` at any position in the href, like `blahgoogle.com`.

Comment: It also naively matches `blahgoogle.com` and `some.com?blah=google.com`. Bad suggestion.

Comment: @BalusC as stated: ``any element that has part of a URL in their href attribute.``

Answer (score 5):

```
var myElement = $("a[href='http://www.stackoverflow.com']");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
$('a[href=\'http://google.com\']')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/