# jQuery: find element with an href of X

Tags: jquery, href, location-href

I need to be able to check the following:

`$(".main-menu a")`

For a specific `href` attribute and then `addClass`

Comment: More detail is going to allow us to actually help you. What exactly are you checking for in the `href` attribute?

Comment: Did you do any research before asking? Questions similar to this have been asked many, many times before. [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105984/how-to-get-element-by-href-in-jquery)

Comment: Yes I have MrOBrian ... but the plethora of questions mean a much wider net of possibilities. It doesn't hurt to ask in my own way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".main-menu a[href='http://somesite.com']").addClass('someClass');
```