# Is it possible to grab a link by its href if it doesn't have a class or ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I'm using someone else's app and want to change the innerHTML in between any < a>< /a> tag that has a certain href. But these links don't have a class or ID associated with them and I can't edit the code to give them classes or ID's. Is there a way to grab a tag by its href in JavaScript? I wanted to do something similar to this:

```
var theLink = document.getElementByHref("example.com");
```

Otherwise, if that is not possible, can I loop through all the links in the page and choose the ones that have the certain href and innerHTML I'm looking for?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Refer to this already answered question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105984/how-to-get-element-by-href-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DOM3-attribute-selector ([jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)) to get all elements that contain a certain text in their `href` attribute. It would look like

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]')
```

However, that might not be what you actually want - not only urls to that domain might contain this string. You might do something like begins-with:

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com"]')
```

but to get an exact and possibly more complex match, you don't get around a custom [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('a[href]').filter( function() {
     return this.hostname == "example.com";
     // or check other properties of the anchor element
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all elements that have the ***example.com*** value in `href` attribute:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NTGQz/

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]');
```

---

You can also try this, just to be more specific and following the OP ***"ideal"*** answer:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ksZhZ/

```
jQuery.fn.getElementsByHref = function(str){ return $('a[href*="' + str + '"]'); };

$(document).ready(function(){        
   elems = $(this).getElementsByHref('example.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has [a lot of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). The one you want here is the attribute selector.

```
$('a[href="example.com"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector:

```
$('a[href="http://example.com"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), you can do this :

```
$('a[href="example.com"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]');
```

This will select the link that has example.com in the href attribute..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="http:google.com"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

ex: linksToGoogle = $('a[href="http://google.com"]');

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="example.com"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this natively with [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) if your users are on [IE8+ or any other browser](http://caniuse.com/queryselector). This method returns an *NodeList* of matching elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="exact/value.html"]');    // exact match
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="partial/value.html"]'); // partial match
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="starts/with"]');        // href starts with
document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".html"]');              // href ends with
```