# How can I add a class to an anchor in a list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, href

I am building a website in Wordpress and need to add a class to the anchor element that is inside a list item. The list item has a unique ID. The class I need to add will give me smooth scrolling on the anchor link.

I do not want to alter the theme, that is why I want to add a class with JavaScript, or any better technique.

This is what I have tried but does not work:

```
$('li#menu-item-318').find('a').addClass('fl-scroll-link');
```

I my Console I get this error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$("#menu-item-318 a")', '$' is undefined) Error: {}
```

This is the specific code on my website:

```
<nav class="top-bar-nav"><ul id="menu-topbalk"><li id="menu-item-318"><a href="#contactgegevens" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li></ul></nav>
```

So the above a tag needs to get this second class: fl-scroll-link so that this will be the result:

```
<a href="#contactgegevens" class="nav-link fl-scroll-link">Contact</a>
```

I am learning every day and could use your help. Please explain the solution you propose.

**// Solution //**

Thanks a lot everyone, together we made it work! Hooray!

So I made 2 mistakes:

1. I was looking for a class but of course should be looking for an id.
2. Wordpress is uses jQuery instead of $!

The working code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-item-318 a").addClass("fl-scroll-link");
});
```

Thanks again, I am very happy!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. Are you loading it _after_ the page renders? Scripting can't act on elements which don't exist.

Comment: is `<li id="menu-item-318"<a href="#contactgegevens"` a typo? Also, your selector `li.menu-item-31` is trying to select the `li` with a _class_ of `menu-item-31`. You're looking for `li#menu-item-31` to select the `li` with an id of `menu-item-31`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById for more info, as well as a similar example in vanilla JS (not using jquery).

Comment: Tip: hit `f12` to see the developer console. Then, you can learn more about *why* things don't work, and then either figure it out on your own or post the reason here. It's called *attaching the stack/error trace*

Comment: `I have also learned that it is good to use classList:` there is nothing wrong with using `addClass` if you already use jQuery. The question is more if it makes sense to use jQuery at all nowadays.

Comment: @Yarin_007 Thanks! I am working on an iPad and have an app installed called Inspect, so I have a Console and see all element. I checked the Console and what do you know, I got an error: `TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$('li#menu-item-318')', '$' is undefined) Error: {}`. I have to research more to find out what it means.

Comment: I believe that WordPress uses `jQuery` instead of `$`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258282/typeerror-is-not-a-function-wordpress

Comment: @j08691 Yesssss, that is it! It works! This works:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-item-318 a").addClass("fl-scroll-link");
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing closure on your list item (or was)

```html
<nav class="top-bar-nav">
  <ul id="menu-topbalk">
    <li id="menu-item-318">  <!-- missing ">" here -->
      <a href="#contactgegevens" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

To add the `fl-scroll-link` class to an anchor use the `.addClass()` method.  Apply this to all of the child `<a>` elements underneath the menu like below.  Since you're already using jquery I've used that also.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-item-318 a").addClass("fl-scroll-link");
});
```

Also if you wanted to actually access it by its anchor href value there is another question that has answered that already here:  [How to get an element by its href in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105984/how-to-get-an-element-by-its-href-in-jquery)

In your case:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href="#contactgegevens"]').addClass("fl-scroll-link");
});
```

The error message about "$" being undefined means that your jquery library isn't being loaded.  You'll want to make sure that your custom javascript is added AFTER the site loads jquery... or below is a pure javascript way to add a class to that `<a>` tag.

```js
document.querySelector('a[href="#contactgegevens"]').classList.add("fl-scroll-link");
```

or if you wanted to apply that class to all `<a>` tags under the list item.

```js
document.querySelector('#menu-item-318 a').classList.add("fl-scroll-link");
```

- https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
- https://jsfiddle.net/3efhkbxa/

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, sharp! Thanks. It does not work. So the error is somewhere else. I got an error in my console, so I have to figure out what it means.

Comment: Ok, well if you want to add that to your original question I can improve my answer further.

Comment: That error means your jquery library isn't loaded.  You'll need something like:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="bin/jquery/jquery.min.js?"></script>`

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for me:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-item-318 a").addClass("fl-scroll-link");
});`

Comment: cool, keep in mind that you would not need additional `jquery(document).ready()` functions, just include all of your javascript in the same document.ready.